# Contstruct url to router another controller in module

Tags: zend-framework2, router

I am new to ZF2. I have question for
    url('route-name', $urlParams, $urlOptions); ?>

What should I construct $urlParams and $urlOptions when multiple controller in module?

I rename Album module as Shop and it has two controllers: indexController and VendorController. In the View>Shop>Vendor>index.phtml, I add:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url('shop', array('action'=>'add')); ?>">
         Add new vendor</a></p>
```

aiming this link would links to localhost/shop/vendor/add. But the page shows the link is:
    http://host.com/shop
while what i want is
    http://host.com/shop/vendor/add

My understanding is that I should set $urlOPtions field, could anyone give me example? Thanks all 
Below is module.config.php:

```
'router' => array(
   'routes' => array(
        'shop' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/shop',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Shop\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Shop\Controller\Index' => 'Shop\Controller\IndexController',
        'Shop\Controller\Vendor'=> 'Shop\Controller\VendorController'
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

The route you're trying to use to construct the url is actually the default child route. So you should use that instead:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url('shop/default', array('action'=>'add')); ?>">
         Add new vendor</a></p>
```

Note the 'shop/default' instead of shop to target the child route.

Also you should specify the controller as a parameter, so you get something like this:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url('shop/default', array('controller' => 'vendor', 'action'=>'add')); ?>">
         Add new vendor</a></p>
```

Comment: It works, thanks Ruben.. How about if we have arguments.. for example. for example.                                              <a href="<?php echo $this->url('shop/default',
            array('controller'=>'vendor', 'action'=>'delete', 'id' => $vendor->vendorId));?>">Delete</a>                           only generates /shop/vendor/delete instead of /shop/vendor/delete/id/34

Comment: @shijiexu that's because the param `id` is not defined in the route

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I changed child router                          'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id]]'         and the url is construct as expected. The question is that if I have multiple urls like  shop/vendor/namevalue  ; shop/vendor/addressValue ; and more arguments shop/vendor/namevalue1/namevalue2/nabmevalue3..  How should I update my child router ? Should I count all possible URLs pattern and construct child-router for each kind url?

Comment: iirc filter-values should be query parameters, anything else is fine for the route itself